# What's the equivalent method of "separation of variables" to solve first order homogeneous linear differential equations using the Lagrange notation?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

Consider the following differential equation:

$$
\frac{df(x)}{dx}+C\cdot f(x)=0
$$

Solving it using the separation of variables method is quite straightforward because the Leibniz notation is very intuitive:

$$
\frac{df(x)}{dx}+C_0\cdot f(x)=0
$$
$$
\frac{df(x)}{dx}=-C_0\cdot f(x)
$$
$$
\frac{1}{f(x)}\cdot df(x)=-C_0 \cdot dx
$$
$$
\int\frac{1}{f(x)}\cdot df(x)=\int-C_0 \cdot dx
$$
$$
ln|f(x)|+C_1=-C_0 \cdot x+C_2
$$
$$
e^{ln|f(x)|}=e^{-C_0 \cdot x+C_3}
$$
$$
f(x)=e^{-C_0 \cdot x+C_3}
$$
$$
f(x)=C_4\cdot e^{-C_0 \cdot x}
$$

Is there an equivalent **intuitive** method for solving this equation using the Lagrange notation or the Newton notation (below)?

$$
f'(x)+C\cdot f(x)=0
$$

$$
y'+C\cdot y=0
$$

$$
\dot{f(x)}+C\cdot f(x)=0
$$

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure how intuitive this is but assuming $f:\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}$ is nowhere vanishing, the ODE can be re-written as
\begin{align}
\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}&=-C
\end{align}
Or, integrating both sides,
\begin{align}
\int\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}\,dx&=\int-C\,dx,
\end{align}
and thus
\begin{align}
\log|f(x)|&=-Cx+a,
\end{align}
for some $a\in\Bbb{R}$. Therefore, $|f(x)|=e^{-Cx+a}$, or rewriting, $f(x)=Ae^{-Cx}$ for some $A\in\Bbb{R}$. This is the exact same calculation written in Lagrange's notation. At some point you just have to recognize that a logarithm must pop up.

---

I should point out that such a separation of variables makes the additional assumption that the function $f$ is nowhere vanishing (otherwise the division is not defined). But the argument can be re-written in such a way so as to not unnecessarily invoke this assumption: simply define $g(x)=f(x)e^{Cx}$, then by the product rule, $g'=0$ identically, so by the mean-value theorem, $g$ must be a constant function, i.e there is an $A\in\Bbb{R}$ such that for all $x\in\Bbb{R}$, $g(x)=f(x)e^{Cx}=A$, thus $f(x)=Ae^{-Cx}$. By the way, this approach works well even if we consider this as a complex differential equation $f:\Bbb{C}\to\Bbb{C}$. The first method using separation of variables is a little iffy because of the use of $\log$, which has many subtleties in the complex plane.

Comment: Sorry, but that's not intuitive at all. In fact it is difficult to understand and follow your method.

Comment: @williantafsilva $\frac{f'}{f}=(\log |f|)'$ is literally the same step as what you wrote $\int\frac{df}{f}=\log|f(x)|$, which you said is intuitive for some reason. You ultimately have to recognize that it is a logarithmic derivative. Otherwise, I could ask you what is so intuitive about $\int\frac{df}{f}=\log|f|$? And your answer would just be "it's a standard rule of anti-differentiation".

Comment: I'm sorry but this is not intuitive because the operations you perform are not symmetric in the LHS and RHS. On the LHS, you have $f'$, which indicates what you are integrating, but there's nothing like that on the RHS. So it's not intuitive.

Comment: @williantafsilva how about now? $\int\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}\,dx=\log|f(x)|$ has to be obvious now; it's just true because if you differentiate $\log|f(x)|$ then you get (chain rule) $\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}$. If you tell me that this is still not intuitive, then I'm sorry but I'm not the right person to answer; you'll just have to wait for someone else.

Answer (score 0):

I think this really just follows on from what **peek-a-boo** said but I will try and word it differently:

$$
\begin{align}
f'(x)+Cf(x)=&0\\
f'(x)=&-Cf(x)\\
\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}=&-C\\
\color{red}{\int}\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}\color{red}{dx}=&\color{red}{\int}(-C)\color{red}{dx}\\
\int\frac1{f(x)}\color{blue}{f'(x)dx}=&-C\int dx\\
\int\frac{df}{f}=&-C\int dx\\
\ln|f|=&-Cx+\color{green}{A}\\
f=&\exp\left(-Cx+A\right)\\
=&\exp(-Cx)\exp(A)\qquad\text{let}\,A_1=\exp(A)\\
=&A_1\exp(-Cx)\\
\therefore\,f(x)=&A_1e^{-Cx}
\end{align}$$
perhaps the most unintuitive step here is justifying that $f'dx=df$, however I would put this down to a shortfall of the notation rather than anything else.

The integrals in red are as such as you can think of this step as "integrating both sides wrt x"